# JSX If a value in a array of Dictionaries is the same, show a message

Tags: arrays, reactjs, loops, dictionary, jsx

I have an array of dictionaries which are group sessions that I show and just in case all of the group sessions are marked not public, I want to display a message instead.

I already have a message that shows if there are no groups, but also want one that shows a different message if there are groups but none are public.

Below is the code I am using.

```
  <div className="sk-asset sk-groups">
      {profile.group_sessions.length > 0 ? profile.group_sessions.reverse().map(group => (
        <div key={group.id}><GroupsCards group={group} /></div>))
    : <p style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 25 }}>More groups coming soon to your area</p> }
  </div>
```

My thoughts are looping through the array to see if all of them are set to is_public = false, but can't figure out how to do that.  If someone has a better suggestion, I am all for it.  Thank you for looking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use filter and check if the result array is empty.

```
if (profile.group_sessions.filter(group => group.is_public).length === 0)
```